# Cross-Reference to Related Applicaitons

Tags: title

> (B) Cross-Reference to Related Applications: (See 37 CFR 1.78 and MPEP
>   Section 200.) If this patent is related to other patents, or based on
>   earlier-filed US applications, it will be stated right after the
>   title. This would include patents based on provisional applications,
>   or which are divisions, continuations or continuations-in-part of
>   other applications. If the earlier applications became patents before
>   this patent issued, the patent numbers will usually be noted here.
>   Sometimes foreign priority applications are listed here, but it is not
>   required. This information may duplicate information on the first
>   page.

[Source hyperlink:](http://www.bpmlegal.com/howtopat4.html)

If a Provisional Application is filed, is the Non Provisional Application a **continuation** of the Provisional?

Would my invention's title be:

Left handed smoke shifter.  **Continuation** of Provisional Application 62/11111111?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a continuation of the provisional. It "claims the benefit of the provisional."

Comment: Left handed smoke shifter, claiming the benefit of Provisional Application 62/11111111?  Always good to hear from you George

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the non provisional application which refers to an earlier priority has to cross refer all earlier applications which it calims priority from.